# RealmSwiftでcommitWriteTransaction()が見つからないというコンパイルエラー

Tags: swift, realm

RealmSwiftの使い方について質問です。

**実行環境**
- OS El Capitan 10.11.1
- Xcode 7.1
- CocoaPods 0.96.2

以下のオブジェクトにデータを入れたいのですがどうしたらいいですか？

```
class User: RLMObject {
    dynamic var id = 0
    dynamic var name = ""

    override class func primaryKey()->String {
        return "id"
    }
}
```

```
let user = User()
user.id = "1"
user.name = "aaaaa"

do {
    let realm = try! RLMRealm.defaultRealm()
    realm.beginWriteTransaction()
    realm.addObject(user)
    realm.commitWriteTransaction() ⇦このメソッドが見当たらなくエラーになります。
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

メソッドが見つからないのではなく、`try`が抜けているだけだと思います。`commitWriteTransaction()`メソッドは失敗する可能性があるので、`throws`が定義されているので、`try`を付けて呼び出す必要があります。

```
realm.beginWriteTransaction()
realm.addObject(user)
try realm.commitWriteTransaction()
```

余談ですが、iOS 8以上を対象にしているなら、RealmSwiftを利用する方が、Swiftらしく型安全でシンプルなコードになります。

https://realm.io/jp/docs/swift/latest/

Comment: ご丁寧に有難うございます！
try! realm.commitWriteTransaction()
で上手く実行ができました。
お手数なのですが、もう一つ質問よろしいですか？
警告が出てこれをクリアしたいです。
翻訳で見てみると理解できなかったです。
エラー：No Calls to throwing functions occur within try expression
Google翻訳：投げ関数への呼び出しなしではtry式内で発生していません
よろしくお願いします。

Comment: @Tkeda `try!`と`try`の違いです。`try!`はエラーの際はクラッシュするので、`do〜 catch`ブロックで囲っていても`error`が`throw`されて`catch`に入ることはないので、警告が出ています。あるいは、提示のコードでは`RLMRealm.defaultRealm()`に`try`を書いていますが、このメソッドはエラーを`throw`しないので`try`は不要という警告です。